# resizing div from only the right corner

Tags: javascript, html, css

So for my project I want to make my card elements smaller when reducing the screen size. However I can't figure out how to let the cards reduce in size correctly. I tried display:flex and flew-flow row wrap but nothing seems to work. So to be clear I want my divs to reduce from right to left Does anyone know how to fix this? Here is my code:

```css
  
.showcase {
    position: relative;
    height:35rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    max-width: 75rem;
}

.showcase_container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap:1rem;
    width:75rem;
}

.showcase_item1 {
    height:15rem;
    width: 23rem;
    background-color: var(--color-showcase);
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgb(9 30 66 / 20%), 0px 0px 1px rgb(9 30 66 / 31%);
}

.showcase_item1 p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:0.9rem;
    margin: 1.10rem 0;
}

.showcase_item1 h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:1.3rem;
}

.arrow1 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:1.8rem;
    margin-left: 19rem;
}

.showcase_item1:hover {
    background: white;
    transition: 200ms;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.showcase_item1:hover .arrow1 {
    display:flex;
    transition: 200ms ease-in;
    transform: translateX(40%);
    margin-right:1rem;
}

.showcase_item1:hover .hide {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:0.9rem;
    margin-left:9rem;
    animation: type 1s steps(60, end)
}

.icondraft1 {
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

.showcase_item2 {
    height:15rem;
    width: 23rem;
    background-color: var(--color-showcase);
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgb(9 30 66 / 20%), 0px 0px 1px rgb(9 30 66 / 31%);
}

.showcase_item2 p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:0.9rem;
    margin: 1.10rem 0;
}

.showcase_item2 h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:1.3rem;
}

.arrow2 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:1.8rem;
    margin-left: 19rem;
}

.showcase_item2:hover {
    background: white;
    transition:450ms;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.showcase_item2:hover .arrow2{
    display:flex;
    transition: 200ms ease-in;
    transform: translateX(40%);
    margin-right:1rem;
}

.showcase_item2:hover .hide {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:0.8rem;
    margin-left:9rem;
}

.icondraft2 {
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.showcase_item3 {
    height: 15rem;
    width: 23rem;
    background-color: var(--color-showcase);
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgb(9 30 66 / 20%), 0px 0px 1px rgb(9 30 66 / 31%);
}

.showcase_item3 p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:0.9rem;
    margin: 1.10rem 0;
}

.showcase_item3 h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:1.3rem;
}

.arrow3 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:2.5rem;
    margin-left: 19rem;
}

.showcase_item3:hover {
    background: white;
    transition:450ms;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.showcase_item3:hover .arrow3{
    display:flex;
    transition: 200ms ease-in;
    transform: translateX(40%);
    margin-right:1rem;
}


.showcase_item3:hover .hide {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:1.5rem;
    margin-left:9rem;
}

.icondraft3 {
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.showcase_item4 {
    height: 15rem;
    width: 23rem;
    background-color: var(--color-showcase);
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgb(9 30 66 / 20%), 0px 0px 1px rgb(9 30 66 / 31%);
}

.showcase_item4 p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:0.9rem;
    margin: 1.10rem 0;
}

.showcase_item4 h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:1.3rem;
    margin: 0.6rem;
}

.arrow4 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:1.5rem;
    margin-left: 19rem;
}

.showcase_item4:hover {
    background: white;
    transition:450ms;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.showcase_item4:hover .arrow4{
    display:flex;
    transition: 200ms ease-in;
    transform: translateX(40%);
    margin-right:1rem;
}

.showcase_item4:hover .hide {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:0.6rem;
    margin-left:9rem;
}

.icondraft4 {
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.showcase_item5 {
    height: 15rem;
    width: 23rem;
    background-color: var(--color-showcase);
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgb(9 30 66 / 20%), 0px 0px 1px rgb(9 30 66 / 31%);
}

.showcase_item5 p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:0.9rem;
    margin: 1.10rem 0;
}

.showcase_item5 h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:1.3rem;
}

.arrow5 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:1rem;
    margin-left: 19rem;
}

.showcase_item5:hover {
    background: white;
    transition:450ms;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.showcase_item5:hover .arrow5{
    display:flex;
    transition: 200ms ease-in;
    transform: translateX(40%);
}

.showcase_item5:hover .hide {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:0.2rem;
    margin-left:9rem;
}


.icondraft5 {
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.showcase_item6 {
    height: 15rem;
    width: 23rem;
    background-color: var(--color-showcase);
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgb(9 30 66 / 20%), 0px 0px 1px rgb(9 30 66 / 31%);
}

.showcase_item6 p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:0.9rem;
    margin: 1.10rem 0;
}

.showcase_item6 h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:1.3rem;
}

.arrow6 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:3rem;
    margin-left: 19rem;
}

.showcase_item6:hover {
    background: white;
    transition:450ms;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.showcase_item6:hover .arrow6{
    display:flex;
    transition: 200ms ease-in;
    transform: translateX(40%);
}

.showcase_item6:hover .hide {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:2.0rem;
    margin-left:9rem;
}

.icondraft6 {
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    .showcase_container {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        width:50rem;
    }
    .showcase {
        height:50rem;
    }
    .showcase_item1 {
        height:15rem;
        width: 21rem;
    }
    .showcase_item2 {
        height:15rem;
        width: 21rem;
    }
    .showcase_item3 {
        height:15rem;
        width: 21rem;
    }
    .showcase_item4 {
        height:15rem;
        width: 21rem;
    }
    .showcase_item5 {
        height:15rem;
        width: 21rem;
    }
    .showcase_item5 p {
        font-size:0.88rem;
    }
    .showcase_item6 {
        height:15rem;
        width: 21rem;
    }

}
@media screen and (max-width: 1201px) {

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .startingbackground_div h1 {
        font-size:2.5rem;
    }
    .nav_menu {
        flex-grow: 2;
        margin-left:2rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1070px) {
    .startingbackground_div p {
        font-size: 0.93rem;
    }
    .startingbackground_div h1 {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
}


@media screen and (max-width: 890px) {
    .nav_menu {
        display:none;
    }
    .login_nav {
        display:none;
    }
    .hamburger {
        display:flex;
    }
    .nav_container {
        padding-left: 0.3rem;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    .startingbackground_container {
        display:block;
        margin-top: 9rem;
    }
    .startingbackground_div p {
        font-size: 1.1rem;
    }
    .startingbackground_div h1 {
        font-size: 2.8rem;
    }
    .startingbackground {
        height: 90vh;
    }
    .solutions {
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }
    .header_left {
        
    }
    
    .showcase_container {
        display: block;
    }

    .showcase_item1 {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        overflow:hidden;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="showcase">
        <div class="container showcase_container">
            <div class="showcase_item1">
                <a href="#" class="linkcard"><span class="icondraft1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path style="line-height:normal;text-indent:0;text-align:start;text-decoration-line:none;text-decoration-style:solid;text-decoration-color:#000;text-transform:none;white-space:normal;isolation:auto;mix-blend-mode:normal;" d="M19.01 1.52v.003H19l-6.33.475h-.037L12.62 2H5.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.602l-1.07.152a.5.5 0 0 0-.424.564L5 14.23V27.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1.477l.08.56a.5.5 0 0 0 .564.424l4.832-.693.422.48a.5.5 0 0 0 .723.032l.826-.795.055-.008H25.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1.154l1.418-.203a.5.5 0 0 0 .424-.565l-1.297-9.043c.096-.07.193-.14.283-.23l.277-.278c.336-.335.61-.714.79-1.109l1.255-2.764c.116-.255.17-.625-.103-.898a.657.657 0 0 0-.455-.195.952.952 0 0 0-.444.093L26 12.13V7.535a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.035v-.014c0-.011 0-.023-.002-.035l-.002-.015a.502.502 0 0 0-.017-.082l-.004-.014a.514.514 0 0 0-.014-.033l-.002-.002-.004-.012a.473.473 0 0 0-.016-.031l-.007-.014-.002-.004a.5.5 0 0 0-.047-.064l-.01-.012a.497.497 0 0 0-.02-.022l-5-5A.5.5 0 0 0 20.5 2H20.154l-.9-.432a.5.5 0 0 0-.244-.048zM6 3h14v4.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H25v4.62a3.32 3.32 0 0 0-.627.484l-.826.824c-.02.02-.03.048-.049.07H7V15h15.516l-2.149 2H7v1h12.291l-2.148 2H7v1h9.068l-2.146 1.998H7V24h5.846l-1.932 1.797a.5.5 0 0 0-.035.695l.445.508H6V3zm15 .707L24.293 7H21V3.707zM5 4.105V7.2l-.436-3.031L5 4.105zM7 8v1h9V8H7zm0 3v1h16.5v-1H7zm20.969 1.334-.987 2.17c-.118.26-.324.557-.584.816l-.277.278a1.131 1.131 0 0 1-.365.25l-1.358-1.358.682-.68a2.23 2.23 0 0 1 .613-.443l2.276-1.033zm-4.256 2.92 1.23 1.23-9.998 9.63-1.361-1.434 10.129-9.426zM25 17.818V27h-9.531l3.113-3H24v-1.002h-4.377L21.697 21H23.5v-1h-.766L25 17.818zm1 1.955.781 5.452-.781.113v-5.565zm-13.148 5.588 1.375 1.446-.946.91-1.33-1.518.9-.838z" color="#000" enable-background="accumulate" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="400" overflow="visible"/></svg></span>
                <h1>Draft</h1>
                <p>Use our in-browser contract drafting solution to<br>draft your contracts.</p>
                <div class="hide">Learn more</div><span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="arrow1" width="32" height="32"><path d="M4 15a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h19.586l-4.292 4.292a1 1 0 0 0 1.414 1.414l6-6a.99.99 0 0 0 .292-.702V15c0-.13-.026-.26-.078-.382a.99.99 0 0 0-.216-.324l-6-6a1 1 0 0 0-1.414 1.414L24.586 14H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1z"/></svg></span>
            </div></a>
            <div class="showcase_item2">
                <a><span class="icondraft2"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="70" height="65" viewBox="0 0 62 60"><path d="M35 14.5c0-1.7-1.3-3-3-3-.5 0-.8-.4-.8-.8V3.8h-6.1V4c-.5 2.1-2.4 3.7-4.6 3.7-2.2 0-4.1-1.5-4.6-3.7v-.2H9.8v20.8c0 .3.3.6.6.6h3.8c.5 0 .8.4.8.8l.2 3.5 5.8-4.1c.1-.1.3-.1.5-.1h9.7v-6.8c0-.5.4-.8.8-.8 1.7-.2 3-1.5 3-3.2z"/><path d="m43 25.4 5.3 3.8.1-3.2c0-.5.4-.8.9-.8l4.3.1c.3 0 .6-.3.6-.6V3.8h-6.8c-.5 0-.8-.4-.8-.8 0-1.7-1.4-3-3-3-1.7 0-3 1.3-3 3 0 .5-.4.8-.8.8H33v6.1h.2c2.1.5 3.7 2.4 3.7 4.6 0 2.2-1.5 4.1-3.7 4.6H33v6.1h9.7s.2.1.3.2zM15.1 49.2C7 49.2.4 55.2.4 62.7v.8c0 .3.2.5.5.5h28.4c.3 0 .5-.2.5-.5v-.8c0-7.4-6.6-13.5-14.7-13.5zm6.8-10.6c0-3.7-3.1-6.8-6.8-6.8-3.7 0-6.8 3-6.8 6.8 0 3.7 3 6.8 6.8 6.8 3.7 0 6.8-3.1 6.8-6.8zm27 10.6c-8.1 0-14.7 6-14.7 13.5v.8c0 .3.2.5.5.5h28.4c.3 0 .5-.2.5-.5v-.8c0-7.4-6.6-13.5-14.7-13.5zm0-17.4c-3.8 0-6.8 3-6.8 6.8 0 3.7 3.1 6.8 6.8 6.8 3.7 0 6.8-3.1 6.8-6.8 0-3.8-3.1-6.8-6.8-6.8z"/></svg></span>
                <h1>Negotiations</h1>
                <p>Comment and make suggestions in contracts<br>using our in-browser negotiating solution.</p>
                <div class="hide">Learn more</div><span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="arrow2" width="32" height="32"><path d="M4 15a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h19.586l-4.292 4.292a1 1 0 0 0 1.414 1.414l6-6a.99.99 0 0 0 .292-.702V15c0-.13-.026-.26-.078-.382a.99.99 0 0 0-.216-.324l-6-6a1 1 0 0 0-1.414 1.414L24.586 14H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1z"/></svg></span>
            </div></a>
            <div class="showcase_item3">
                <a><span class="icondraft3"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 256.001 256.001"><rect width="256" height="256" fill="none"/><line x1="128.001" x2="128.001" y1="108" y2="216" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"/><line x1="128.001" x2="128.001" y1="40" y2="68" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"/><circle cx="128.001" cy="88" r="20" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"/><line x1="200.001" x2="200.002" y1="188" y2="216" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"/><line x1="200.002" x2="200.001" y1="40" y2="148" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"/><circle cx="200.001" cy="168" r="20" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"/><line x1="56.001" x2="56" y1="156" y2="216" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"/><line x1="56" x2="56.001" y1="40" y2="116" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"/><circle cx="56.001" cy="136" r="20" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"/></svg></span>
                <h1>CPQ</h1>
                <p>Configure price quotes easily by using our<br>integrated solution. </p>
                <div class="hide">Learn more</div><span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="arrow3" width="32" height="32"><path d="M4 15a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h19.586l-4.292 4.292a1 1 0 0 0 1.414 1.414l6-6a.99.99 0 0 0 .292-.702V15c0-.13-.026-.26-.078-.382a.99.99 0 0 0-.216-.324l-6-6a1 1 0 0 0-1.414 1.414L24.586 14H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1z"/></svg></span>
            </div></a>
            <div class="showcase_item4">
                <a><span class="icondraft4"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="87" height="55" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><path d="M180.9 255.9H31.3c-7.9 0-14.3-6.4-14.3-14.3V14.3C17 6.4 23.4 0 31.3 0h149.6c7.9 0 14.3 6.4 14.3 14.3v79.5c0 1.4-1.1 2.5-2.5 2.5s-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5V14.3c0-5.2-4.2-9.4-9.4-9.4H31.3c-5.2 0-9.4 4.2-9.4 9.4v227.2c0 5.2 4.2 9.4 9.4 9.4h149.6c5.2 0 9.4-4.2 9.4-9.4v-55.8c0-1.4 1.1-2.5 2.5-2.5s2.5 1.1 2.5 2.5v55.8c0 8-6.5 14.4-14.4 14.4z"/><path d="M167.5 34.3H42.7c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5s1.1-2.5 2.5-2.5h124.8c1.4 0 2.5 1.1 2.5 2.5s-1.2 2.5-2.5 2.5zm1 30.9H43.7c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5s1.1-2.5 2.5-2.5h124.8c1.4 0 2.5 1.1 2.5 2.5s-1.1 2.5-2.5 2.5zm-1 38.3H42.7c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5s1.1-2.5 2.5-2.5h124.8c1.4 0 2.5 1.1 2.5 2.5s-1.2 2.5-2.5 2.5zm0 38.3H42.7c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5s1.1-2.5 2.5-2.5h124.8c1.4 0 2.5 1.1 2.5 2.5s-1.2 2.5-2.5 2.5zm-8.3 38.3H42.6c-1.4 0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5s1.1-2.5 2.5-2.5h116.5c1.4 0 2.5 1.1 2.5 2.5s-1.1 2.5-2.4 2.5zM78 239.7H54.4c-7.8 0-14.2-6.4-14.2-14.2v-5.3c0-7.8 6.4-14.2 14.2-14.2H78c7.8 0 14.2 6.4 14.2 14.2v5.3c0 7.8-6.4 14.2-14.2 14.2zm-23.6-28.8c-5.1 0-9.3 4.2-9.3 9.3v5.3c0 5.1 4.2 9.3 9.3 9.3H78c5.1 0 9.3-4.2 9.3-9.3v-5.3c0-5.1-4.2-9.3-9.3-9.3H54.4zm85.3 17.9c-.3 0-.7 0-1-.1-1.7-.3-3.3-1.3-4.2-2.8l-3.2-5c-.3-.5-.9-.6-1.1-.6-.2 0-.7 0-1.1.6l-3 4.5c-1.5 2.2-4.2 3.2-6.8 2.5-2.6-.7-4.4-2.9-4.5-5.6l-.6-12.1c0-.9-.7-1.1-1-1.2-.3-.1-1-.1-1.4.7l-7.4 14.4c-.6 1.2-2.1 1.7-3.3 1.1-1.2-.6-1.7-2.1-1.1-3.3l7.4-14.4c1.3-2.5 4-3.8 6.8-3.2 2.8.6 4.7 2.9 4.9 5.7l.6 12.1c0 .8.7 1.1.9 1.2.3.1.9.2 1.4-.5l3-4.5c1.2-1.7 3.1-2.8 5.2-2.7 2.1 0 4 1.1 5.1 2.9l3.2 5c.3.4.7.5.9.6.2 0 .6 0 1-.3l21.5-17c1.1-.8 2.6-.7 3.4.4.8 1.1.7 2.6-.4 3.4l-21.5 17c-1 .7-2.4 1.2-3.7 1.2z"/><path d="M192.8 188.7c-.3 0-.7-.1-1-.2l-34-14.9c-.6-.3-1.1-.7-1.3-1.4-.2-.6-.2-1.3 0-1.9l38.9-88.7c3.2-7.3 11.7-10.6 19-7.4l12 5.3c3.5 1.6 6.3 4.4 7.7 8 1.4 3.6 1.3 7.5-.2 11.1L195 187.3c-.3.6-.7 1.1-1.4 1.3-.2 0-.5.1-.8.1zm-30.7-18.6 29.5 13 37.9-86.4c1-2.3 1.1-4.9.2-7.3-.9-2.4-2.7-4.2-5.1-5.3l-12-5.3c-4.8-2.1-10.5.1-12.6 4.9l-37.9 86.4z"/><path d="M229.2 86.7c-.3 0-.7-.1-1-.2-1.2-.5-1.8-2-1.3-3.2l3.2-7.3c.5-1.1.7-2.2.7-3.4 0-3.3-2-6.4-5-7.7-2.1-.9-4.3-1-6.4-.1-2.1.8-3.7 2.4-4.6 4.5l-3.2 7.3c-.5 1.2-2 1.8-3.2 1.3-1.2-.5-1.8-2-1.3-3.2l3.2-7.3c1.4-3.3 4-5.8 7.4-7.1 3.3-1.3 6.9-1.2 10.2.2 4.8 2.1 8 6.9 8 12.2 0 1.8-.4 3.6-1.1 5.3l-3.2 7.3c-.6.8-1.5 1.4-2.4 1.4zm-36.9 65.1c-1.7 0-3.4-.4-5-1.1-6.3-2.8-9.2-10.2-6.4-16.5l14.4-32.7c1.3-3.1 3.8-5.4 6.9-6.6 3.1-1.2 6.5-1.1 9.6.2 3.1 1.3 5.4 3.8 6.6 6.9 1.2 3.1 1.1 6.5-.2 9.6l-14.4 32.7c-1.3 3.1-3.8 5.4-6.9 6.6-1.6.6-3.1.9-4.6.9zM206.6 99c-.9 0-1.9.2-2.8.5-1.9.7-3.4 2.2-4.2 4l-14.4 32.7c-1.7 3.8.1 8.3 3.9 10 1.9.8 3.9.9 5.8.1 1.9-.7 3.4-2.2 4.2-4l14.4-32.7c.8-1.9.9-3.9.1-5.8-.7-1.9-2.2-3.4-4-4.2-.9-.4-1.9-.6-3-.6zm-44.7 113.5c-.3 0-.7-.1-1-.2-.8-.4-1.4-1.1-1.5-2l-3.3-39.3c-.1-.9.3-1.7 1-2.2.7-.5 1.6-.6 2.4-.2l34.4 15.1c.8.3 1.3 1.1 1.4 1.9.1.9-.2 1.7-.9 2.2l-31 24.2c-.5.3-1 .5-1.5.5zm-.5-37.8 2.6 30.7 24.3-18.9-26.9-11.8z"/></svg></span>
                <h1>eSignatures</h1>
                <p>Use our eSignature tool to get your documents<br>signed.</p>
                <div class="hide">Learn more</div><span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  class="arrow4" width="32" height="32"><path d="M4 15a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h19.586l-4.292 4.292a1 1 0 0 0 1.414 1.414l6-6a.99.99 0 0 0 .292-.702V15c0-.13-.026-.26-.078-.382a.99.99 0 0 0-.216-.324l-6-6a1 1 0 0 0-1.414 1.414L24.586 14H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1z"/></svg></span>
            </div></a>
            <div class="showcase_item5">
                <a><span class="icondraft5"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="60" viewBox="0 0 64 64"><path fill="#231f20" d="M53.987,49.063c0-.022.013-.041.013-.063V5a3,3,0,0,0-3-3H13a3,3,0,0,0-3,3V59a3,3,0,0,0,3,3H41a1.005,1.005,0,0,0,.707-.293l12-12a1,1,0,0,0,.2-.293c.014-.031.022-.062.033-.094A.945.945,0,0,0,53.987,49.063ZM12,59V5a1,1,0,0,1,1-1H51a1,1,0,0,1,1,1V48H43a3,3,0,0,0-3,3v9H13A1,1,0,0,1,12,59Zm30-.414V51a1,1,0,0,1,1-1h7.586Z"/><path fill="#231f20" d="M23 22H19a1 1 0 0 1-1-1 1 1 0 0 0-2 0 3 3 0 0 0 3 3h1v1a1 1 0 0 0 2 0V24h1a3 3 0 0 0 3-3V19a3 3 0 0 0-3-3H19a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V13a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h4a1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 0 3 3 0 0 0-3-3H22V9a1 1 0 0 0-2 0v1H19a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v2a3 3 0 0 0 3 3h4a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v2A1 1 0 0 1 23 22zM31 13H47a1 1 0 0 0 0-2H31a1 1 0 0 0 0 2zM31 21H47a1 1 0 0 0 0-2H31a1 1 0 0 0 0 2zM31 29H47a1 1 0 0 0 0-2H31a1 1 0 0 0 0 2zM17 37H47a1 1 0 0 0 0-2H17a1 1 0 0 0 0 2zM47 45a1 1 0 0 0 0-2H17a1 1 0 0 0 0 2z"/></svg></span>
                <h1>Auto-Invoicing</h1>
                <p>Use our powerful auto-invoicing solution in<br>combinations with our CPQ and eSginature tools to<br>always sent accurate invoices on time.</p>
                <div class="hide">Learn more</div><span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  class="arrow5" width="32" height="32"><path d="M4 15a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h19.586l-4.292 4.292a1 1 0 0 0 1.414 1.414l6-6a.99.99 0 0 0 .292-.702V15c0-.13-.026-.26-.078-.382a.99.99 0 0 0-.216-.324l-6-6a1 1 0 0 0-1.414 1.414L24.586 14H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1z"/></svg></span>
            </div></a>
            <div class="showcase_item6">
                <a><span class="icondraft6"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="Layer 1" width="45" height="49" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M27,16.589V7.50049a.48365.48365,0,0,0-.01306-.06561.45541.45541,0,0,0-.01215-.06116.49171.49171,0,0,0-.12-.22479l-.00128-.00244-7-7A.4919.4919,0,0,0,19.626.02509.46407.46407,0,0,0,19.56543.013.48088.48088,0,0,0,19.5,0H5.5A2.50263,2.50263,0,0,0,3,2.5v27A2.50263,2.50263,0,0,0,5.5,32H23.583a.47574.47574,0,0,0,.08374-.01691C23.77814,31.98773,23.88751,32,24,32a7.9969,7.9969,0,0,0,3-15.411ZM20,1.70709,25.29254,7H21.5A1.50164,1.50164,0,0,1,20,5.5ZM19.51263,7H7.5A.50065.50065,0,0,1,7,6.5v-2A.50065.50065,0,0,1,7.5,4H19V5.5A2.47615,2.47615,0,0,0,19.51263,7ZM5.5,31A1.50164,1.50164,0,0,1,4,29.5V2.5A1.50164,1.50164,0,0,1,5.5,1H19V3H7.5A1.50164,1.50164,0,0,0,6,4.5v2A1.50164,1.50164,0,0,0,7.5,8H26v8.26331A7.886,7.886,0,0,0,20.13562,17H12.5a.5.5,0,0,0,0,1h6.22626a7.99915,7.99915,0,0,0-2.463,4H12.5a.5.5,0,0,0,0,1h3.56946a7.75149,7.75149,0,0,0,.51953,4H12.5a.5.5,0,0,0,0,1h4.58246a8.05139,8.05139,0,0,0,3.05316,3ZM24,31a7,7,0,1,1,7-7A7.00818,7.00818,0,0,1,24,31Zm0-13a6,6,0,1,0,6,6A6.00656,6.00656,0,0,0,24,18Zm0,11a5,5,0,1,1,5-5A5.00589,5.00589,0,0,1,24,29Zm2.25-5.5h-.84192A1.45561,1.45561,0,0,0,24.5,22.58759V21.25a.5.5,0,0,0-1,0v1.3421a1.49652,1.49652,0,0,0,.31348,2.89618,1.55361,1.55361,0,0,0,.18945.01172,1.49554,1.49554,0,0,0,1.40936-1H26.25a.5.5,0,0,0,0-1Zm-1.94336.895A.50007.50007,0,1,1,23.999,23.5a.55371.55371,0,0,1,.06348.00391.50011.50011,0,0,1,.24414.89111Zm-14.168-14.24121-2.542,2.65186L6.83594,12.127a.50006.50006,0,1,0-.666.74609l1.12109,1a.50081.50081,0,0,0,.69434-.02686l2.876-3a.50041.50041,0,0,0-.72266-.69238Zm0,5-2.542,2.65186L6.83594,17.127a.50006.50006,0,1,0-.666.74609l1.12109,1a.50081.50081,0,0,0,.69434-.02686l2.876-3a.50041.50041,0,0,0-.72266-.69238Zm0,5-2.542,2.65186L6.83594,22.127a.50006.50006,0,1,0-.666.74609l1.12109,1a.50081.50081,0,0,0,.69434-.02686l2.876-3a.50041.50041,0,0,0-.72266-.69238Zm0,5-2.542,2.65186L6.83594,27.127a.50006.50006,0,1,0-.666.74609l1.12109,1a.50081.50081,0,0,0,.69434-.02686l2.876-3a.50041.50041,0,0,0-.72266-.69238ZM12.5,13h11a.5.5,0,0,0,0-1h-11a.5.5,0,0,0,0,1Z"/></svg></span>
                <h1>Kan-Ban-board</h1>
                <p>Our customizable Kan-Ban boards help you<br> keep track of deadlines and other</p>
                <div class="hide">Learn more</div><span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  class="arrow6" width="32" height="32"><path d="M4 15a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h19.586l-4.292 4.292a1 1 0 0 0 1.414 1.414l6-6a.99.99 0 0 0 .292-.702V15c0-.13-.026-.26-.078-.382a.99.99 0 0 0-.216-.324l-6-6a1 1 0 0 0-1.414 1.414L24.586 14H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1z"/></svg></span>
            </div></a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: You have no idea how many times i reread the question and still have no clue what you're asking for.

Comment: I want the div to stay the same height and reduce the width correctly. When I reduce the screen size now, a big part of the div disappears but it should only get smaller. To get an idea try and use this link: https://doc.primekey.com/signserver . When you reduce the screen size you get the result I want to get on my project, namely that the divs stack above each other and the div will reduce correctly in width without losing part of its content.

Comment: well they already are doing that, but you can't see it because you `overflow:hidden` on `.showcase`

Comment: I don't want to have an overflow. The point is that the card doesn't fully show when reducing the screen size at the moment. If you reduce the screensize on the link I sent you can see the edges on the border of the div still in tact, whereas mine is not.

Comment: first of all that is not something that can easily be controlled, you will have to either set fixed heights, or do some babysitting on every breakpoint, Second on that website it does not do what you're describing, the cards edges are indeed cut off when they wrap.

Comment: Yes the edges are cut off, but my divs edges are partly hidden when reducing the screen size. I don't want my edges to disappear when reducing the screen size you see. You can see this at my example because of the simple fact that my border shadow disappeared when reducing the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) property

```css
.resizable {
  resize: both;
}

.box50 {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box50 resizable">
  Resize me
</div>
```